# The --backends flag for Google App Engine's dev_appserver doesn't seem to be supported?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend

I'm trying to test out my Google App Engine Python backend code locally.  According to the docs there is a flag, --backends, for dev_appserver that will let you run them locally.  I'm using 1.8, and I get this error when I try to use that flag:

error:

dev_appserver.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --backends

Am I doing something wrong, or does this flag not exist?  The docs say it does.  But it's not listed on the help output for dev_appserver either.

I also got this error with the previous 1.7.X version (updated today)

Comment: I don't want to answer my own question just yet, but I got this working using old_dev_appserver ... why is this in old_dev_appserver but not the default one?  old_dev_appserver seems to be a completely different version, not just one release behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [The New Python Development Server](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/old_devserver#New_Development_Server):

> The following flags have been added, removed, or renamed:
>
> - `--backends` has been removed, as it is now always enabled

It should "just work" with the current dev_appserver.

Comment: You are totally right!  It does work--I think that in the process of using the old_dev_appserver I fixed the real bug which is putting the x.localhost in my hosts file--x being the name of the backend.  That's probably why it didn't work in the first place.  But now when I run it with both versions of the appserver it works.  Cool!